# How can I associate a specific calendar to an EKEventEditViewController instance

Tags: swift4, eventkit, ekevent

I'm trying to use the generic `EKEventEditViewController` instead of rolling my own. But I'm running into a problem with the calendar selection. In the controller instance, I see a choice of calendars, and I'd prefer not to see that choice -- I want all events to link to an app-specific calendar.

Is there a way to do this?

Right now, I'm calling `EKEventEditViewController` as follows:

```
@IBAction func addEventTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // create an instance of EKEventEditViewController()
    let eventViewController: EKEventEditViewController = EKEventEditViewController()

    let calendars = eventStore.calendars(for: EKEntityType.event)

    for calendar in calendars {
        if calendar.title == "MyAppCalendar" {

            print("calendar is identified")
            eventViewController.eventStore = self.eventStore
            eventViewController.eventStore.calendar(withIdentifier: calendar.title)
        }
    }

    eventViewController.editViewDelegate = self
    self.present(eventViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by subclassing `EKEventEditViewController`

The code was lifted from [Andrew Bancroft](https://github.com/andrewcbancroft/EventTracker) and from [SpaceOTechnologies](https://www.spaceotechnologies.com/make-calendar-event-reminder-app-event-kit-framework/)

I created an AddEventController and the code is:

```
import UIKit
import EventKit
import EventKitUI

class AddEventViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

    var calendar: EKCalendar!

    @IBOutlet weak var eventNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var eventStartDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var eventEndDatePicker: UIDatePicker!

    var delegate: EventAddedDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.eventStartDatePicker.setDate(initialDatePickerValue(), animated: false)
        self.eventEndDatePicker.setDate(initialDatePickerValue(), animated: false)


    }

    func initialDatePickerValue() -> Date {

        eventNameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

        let calendarUnitFlags: NSCalendar.Unit = [.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]

        var dateComponents = (Calendar.current as NSCalendar).components(calendarUnitFlags, from: Date())

        dateComponents.hour = 0
        dateComponents.minute = 0
        dateComponents.second = 0

        if eventStartDatePicker.isFirstResponder == true {
            eventStartDatePicker.resignFirstResponder()
        }

        if eventEndDatePicker.isFirstResponder == true {
            eventEndDatePicker.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        return Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)!
    }

    @IBAction func cancelButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func addEventButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        // Create an Event Store instance
        let eventStore = EKEventStore()

        let calendars = eventStore.calendars(for: EKEntityType.event)
        for calendar in calendars {
            if calendar.title == "PhotoBase" {
                let newEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)

                newEvent.calendar = calendar
                newEvent.title = self.eventNameTextField.text ?? "Some Event Name"
                newEvent.startDate = self.eventStartDatePicker.date
                newEvent.endDate = self.eventEndDatePicker.date
                // Save the event using the Event Store instance
                do {
                    try eventStore.save(newEvent, span: .thisEvent, commit: true)
                    delegate?.eventDidAdd()

                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                } catch {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Event could not save", message: (error as NSError).localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(OKAction)

                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)  {
        eventNameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print(#file, #function)
        textField.resignFirstResponder();
        return true;
    }
```

I'm open to improvements!